# Remove PDF "security settings"

Tags: pdf

On Android, is there a way or an application that can be used to remove the "security settings" on a PDF so it can be edited? The file in question does NOT have a password, so one it not needed to make it editable again.

Comment: Is there no password needed to remove the security settings or is the PDF protected in a different way? Were you able to remove the security settings of that PDF file using a PDF program on a PC?

Answer (score 0):

One could use some online website, eg https://smallpdf.com/unlock-pdf, to remove the "security settings" on a PDF so it can be edited.

Note that one can't use the usual trick to print the PDF in Chrome to remove its security because on Android, Chrome cannot open PDF files.